# Por que no me muestra el CrystalReportView?

Tags: c#, webforms, crystal-reports

Buen dia! quiero poder ver un crystal report en webforms, sin embargo no me lo muestra, mi codigo es el siguiente
protected void DadosPdtesbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
       /*Dados pendientes es un Dataset que cree con las columnas de Prioridad, Prensa, Dado,Copia,Tiempo y ajustador*/
        DadosPendientes ds = new DadosPendientes();
        int filas = GridView1.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i <= filas - 1; i++)
        {

            string Prioridad = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
            string Prensa = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            string Dado = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            string Copia = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
            string Tiempo = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
            string Ajustador = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
            if (Ajustador == "&nbsp;") {
                Ajustador = string.Empty;
            }
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { Prioridad, Prensa, Dado, Copia, Tiempo, Ajustador });


        }

        /*el ReporteDadosPdtes es un .rpt que cree con ese nombre*/
        ReporteDadosPdtes rep = new ReporteDadosPdtes();
        rep.SetDataSource(ds);

        
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

}